# Почему не работает onmouseout в JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
var SendButt = document.getElementById("sendbutt");

  SendButt.onmouseover = function(e) {
     console.log('мышка пришла');
     SendButt.disabled = true;
  };

  SendButt.onmouseout = function(e) {
    console.log('мышка ушла');
    SendButt.disabled = false;
  }
```

```html
<input id="ni" type="number" name="num" value=""><br>
<button id="sendbutt" type="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Первое событие срабатывает, второе onmouseout уже нет... Потому что кнопку отключили? Или косяк в другом?

Comment: это все из-за `disabled`

Comment: В Chrome действительно не работает, а вот в Firefox нормально работает, возможно это баг хрома

Comment: Хотя в IE11 и Edge тоже не работает

Comment: @ddeadlink ок обернём в div и всё равно не работает ))

Comment: В спецификации хрома где-то указано что ивенты не будут хэндлится (увы не могу найти), если элемент дизейблд, Это скорее кривая особенность фаерфокса , нежели фича. Для кросс-браузерного варианта Вам нужно делать стилевую иммитацию эффекта дизейбла

Comment: @ddeadlink да, спасибо, просто к стилевой имитации придётся ещё писать что бы клик по кнопке не работал, а это печально )))

Comment: Я тут почитал спецификацию HTML 5.1 и нашёл только *«A form control that is **disabled** must prevent any **click** events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.»*. Запрета на mouseover и mouseout мне найти не удалось, так что предположу, что именно Firefox ведёт себя правильно, а у всех остальных браузеров это баг

Comment: @andreymal это вы читали стандартизацию w3, которую не все особо и следуют . Вот пример из ИЕ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732(v=vs.85).aspx . "When an element is disabled, it appears dimmed and does not respond to user input. Disabled elements do not respond to mouse events.."

Comment: @ddeadlink стандартом являются только W3 или WHATWG спецификации. Если браузеры им не следуют, это проблемы браузеров, и всем должно быть глубоко плевать что там написано на всяких левых msdn

Comment: @andreymal с каких пор какой-то левый спек ИЕ стал левым?) Я просто привел пример того, что стандарты ИЕ не совпадают с стандартами w3 который априори является важнее. Так что, это не проблема браузеров, а разработчиков которые работают с ихним dom-api)

Comment: @ddeadlink с каких пор ИЕ перестал быть левой маргинальщиной, которую все избегают?))

Comment: @andreymal я не спорю с Вами, а по своему соглашаюсь)

Comment: @ddeadlink Посмотрел WHATWG — там тоже упоминается только click. А больше я никого за стандарты не считают. Но если вы уж считаете MSDN чем-то важным, то вот вам цитата из MDN, который относится к конкурирующему Firefox: *«Тем не менее, элемент всё ещё будет отвечать событиям, связанным с мышью (т.е. реагировать на mouse events)»* Это всё очень странно, однако

Comment: Потому что гладиолус, с спеках указано, что [должен работать](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#mouseover) и [disable отключает только click события](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled).

Comment: @andreymal, в FF это был [14летний баг](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218093), который пофиксили сравнительно недавно :-)

Comment: @Grundy лол. Открыл в старом Pale Moon — и правда не работает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить стандартам, то такое поведение не должно быть. В спецификациях указано, что [должен работать](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#mouseover) и [disable отключает только click события](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled). В любом случае всегда есть альтернативы.

```js
var SendButt = document.getElementById("sendbutt");
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    if(e.target == SendButt)
        SendButt.disabled = true;
    else
        SendButt.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="ni" type="number" name="num" value=""><br>
<button id="sendbutt" type="submit">Отправить</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

В хроме всё глобальный объект, не знаю какие там спецификации браузера но вот так работает через дополнительный div c addEventListener

```js
var Cover = document.getElementById("my");
var SendButt = document.getElementById("sendbutt");

Cover.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
     console.log('мышка пришла');
     SendButt.disabled = true;
  });

Cover.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    console.log('мышка ушла');
    SendButt.disabled = false;
  });
```

```css
#my{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="ni" type="number" name="num" value=""><br>
<div id="my">
  <button id="sendbutt" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Один из побочных эффектов, кнопка становится неактивной в любой точке дива, даже если в ней нет кнопки. К примеру, если увести мышку правее кнопки.

Comment: @Alex Krass согласен есть такой недостаток, ваше решение лучше

Comment: @AlexKrass поправимо через CSS, ваше решение не лучше)

Comment: @andreymal Вам надо особое приглашение для предоставления ответа лучше?)) Ну можете считать, что я его сейчас Вам выслал.

Comment: @AlexKrass меня этот ответ с дивом вполне устраивает

Comment: @andreymal что поправимо через CSS можете уточнить? У меня по этому варианту при большой скорости движения мышки проскакивает как-то через DIV и кнопка всё равно остаётся отключеной

Comment: @andreymal мне все еще интересно, как Вы это поправите через CSS, я никого за язык не тянул. Если ответ можно сделать лучше, то почему бы и нет?

Comment: @AlexKrass display: inline-block хоспаде, основы css же

Comment: Однако я тут потыкал на мобильнике и действительно иногда "проскакивает", как @fosh4455 говорит, эх

Comment: @andreymal в первую очередь я написал такой же ответ и найдя ошибку проверил этот вариант CSS в первую очередь. А да, оно не работает так, как вы того хотели бы: https://jsfiddle.net/a7httu9o/. Поэтому переписал на mousemove. Хоспаде, лишь бы поумничать)

Comment: @AlexKrass хоспаде, так написали бы про это сразу в первом комментарии и недоразумений не было бы)

Comment: @andreymal ну я же не знал, какой вариант исправления имеется ввиду. Вот тактично и намекнул его озвучить, мало ли, что-то другое было бы.

Comment: @AlexKrass ну вообще эта проблема имеется тут и без исправления (просто не так заметна из-за пустоты справа), так что ладно, ваше решение лучше)

Comment: @andreymal дергать каждый раз `mousemove` при любом движении мыши тоже так себе идея, поэтому я бы предпочел что-то получше и моего варианта тоже. Поэтому если надумаете что-то лучше, буду рад увидеть. При этом mousemove на контейнер тоже не срабатывает, пришлось цеплять к document, в чем я так же вижу проблему :/